# Delete selected elements on the JList while ALT + click

Tags: java, swing, jlist, key-bindings, listselectionlistener

I have a `JList`.
I would like to delete already selected  values whenever i  press ALT + mouseclick the same time on the list. How to do that? I don't know which listener to use.

The problem is that when I have selected values and click on the list again the old selection is lost, new item is selected.

I did:

```
        list.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        ...

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                int[] selected = list.getSelectedIndices();     
                if(selected.length > 0 && (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.ALT_MASK) == InputEvent.ALT_MASK ){
                    System.out.println("tu ");
                    for(int i: selected){
                        model.remove(i);
                    }
                }

            }
....
}
```

**But the problem is that only one element is deleted. This one on which i alt click**

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You probably have some issues with indices. Imagine you have selected item 1, 3 and 5. You remove item 1--> item 3 and 5, now become item 2 and 4, but you request to remove item 3 (which will actually remove the original item 4) and eventually you request to remove item 5 (which would actually be the original item 7). Consider first fetching all objects and then remove them by instance instead of by index or sort the indixes in reverse order and remove them by indices

Comment: Also make sure that your ALT-mouse click does not alter the selection before your listener is triggered ...

Comment: @Robin that is only my problem! How to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that when I have selected values and click on the list again the old selection is lost, new item is selected.

Alt+mousePressed is used to change the selection. This is a common usage of the Alt key. Try playing with this key combination on any application (ie. Windows Explorer) to see how it works.

So a better implementation would probably be to use a different mouse+key combination. I'm not sure what the standards are but I would suggest that for maybe just the "Delete" key could be used delete the selected items. Of course you should popup a confirm dialog. For using the mouse I would use a popup menu that would display on a right click and the menu would contain a Delete action. Again a confirm dialog should display.

Remember any time you build an application the user should be able to use the Keyboard or the mouse to achieve an Action.